# Blazor - How to create Components dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I want to test if it was possible to create Blazor components dynamically.

I can't find any way to do this. I have experimented a bit with some dynamic content found on [this link](https://learn-blazor.com/pages/dynamic-content/) but have not ended up with any results.

Comment: Please add more of your use case and code, what exactly are you trying to accomplish? What have you tried, and where does it fail?

Comment: Sorry for late response - your answer covers my needs, thanks.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/advanced-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-3.1#manual-rendertreebuilder-logic

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For version 0.2 this is the answer from Steve Sanderson:

> We'll implement nicer APIs to build RenderFragments in the future, but
>   for now you can
>
> ```
> @CreateDynamicComponent();
> @functions {
>     RenderFragment CreateDynamicComponent() => builder =>
>     {
>         builder.OpenComponent(0, typeof(SurveyPrompt));
>         builder.AddAttribute(1, "Title", "Some title");
>         builder.CloseComponent();
>     };
> }
> ```
>
> Those are very low-level APIs (not even documented) so we hope not
>   many people need to do this right now. Higher-level APIs for this will
>   come later.

Found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/16104#issuecomment-385713669)

Comment: "we hope not many people need to do this"  - well any designer app has to have the ability to add components dynamically. WYSIWYG editors, process modelling UI, dashboarding UI...so it is not rare and extraterrestrial requirement...

Comment: Maybe it is low level, but it has documentation [RenderTreeBuilder.OpenComponent Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.rendering.rendertreebuilder.opencomponent?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_Rendering_RenderTreeBuilder_OpenComponent__1_System_Int32_)

Answer (score 55):

Judging by the comments on the accepted answer and on the original version of this answer I think there may be a bit of confusion around dynamically adding components.  There are (at least) a couple of ways to achieve this (and a number of existing questions on this, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50299409/add-list-of-dynamic-components-in-blazor)). It all depends on exactly what you mean by 'dynamically':

## 1) Using conditional statements in your Razor code

If what you're trying to achieve is simply to show or hide components based on some state in your data or model, then the 'normal' way to render a component dynamically is to use some sort of conditional code in your Razor view.

### Simple conditional rendering

```cs
@if (_showCounter)
{
  <MyCounterComponent Count="@_count" />
}

@code {
  bool _showCounter = true;
  int _count;
}
```

### Simple repeating data sets

For repeating sets of data, such as lists of items you can take advantage of Blazor's data binding.

Take the example of a page/component that shows a sales order and then has a child component for each sales order line.  You might have code that looks like this on your razor page:

```cs
  @foreach (var salesOrderLine in _salesOrder.salesOrderlines)
  {
    <SalesOrderLine SOLine=@salesOrderLine />
  };
```

If you had a button that added another sales order line then you could simply add the new record to the `_salesOrder` model/view model in that buttons click event.
Button clicks normally trigger a re-render, so the page should then automatically show an extra `SalesOrderLine` component (and if it doesn't you can use `this.StateHasChanged();` to tell it things are different and cause a re-render)

### Repeating data sets containing different data types (possibly polymorphic)

If your list contains different types you can use a switch statement to decide which type of component to render, e.g. (from [this GitHub question](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/14599#issue-500623862)):

> ```cs
> <ul>
>     @foreach (fruit in fruits)
>     {
>         switch(fruit)
>         {
>             case PearComponent p:
>                 <PearComponent ParameterOfSomeSort="p"></PearComponent>
>                 <li>Or render pears like this, if you want the li in it</li>
>                 break;
>             case AppleComponent a:
>                 <AppleComponent></AppleComponent>
>                 break;
>             case BananaComponent b:
>                 <BananaComponent></BananaComponent>
>                 break;
>             case RaspberryComponent r:
>                 <RaspberryComponent></RaspberryComponent>
>                 break;
>         }
>     }
> </ul>
> ```

## 2. Dynamic rendering using RenderFragment

There are some cases that can't be handled well using the Razor approach above.  In those cases `RenderFragment` offers another way to dynamically render parts of a page.

### Polymorphic lists

Where you have a truly polymorphic list (e.g. a list of objects that all implement the same interface or inherit from the same class) then this type of approach can be used [from this GitHub post](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/14599#issuecomment-537443080):

> ```cs
> @page "/"
>
> @foreach (CounterParent counter in components)
> {
>     RenderFragment renderFragment = (builder) => { builder.OpenComponent(0, counter.GetType()); builder.CloseComponent(); };
>     <div>
>         <div>Before the component</div>
>         @renderFragment
>         <div>Afterthe component</div>
>     </div>
> }
>
> @code
> {
>     List<CounterParent> components = new List<CounterParent>() { new CounterParent(), new CounterChild() };
> }
> ```

The Blazor team are [considering improving how polymorphic lists are handled](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/14599#issuecomment-537129104) in Blazor:

> **mkArtakMSFT commented on 1 Oct 2019** Thanks for contacting us, @Joebeazelman. Using the switch approach you have will be our
> recommendation. We will consider doing something better in this area
> in the future.

## Conclusion

The key point here (for those from an MVC background) is that there's no need to try and manually inject the new HTML into the DOM, or dynamically load a partial view, in the way you might of in MVC, Blazor will do that for you.

Despite the similarity in syntax between razor pages for MVC and those for Blazor, the Blazor model is conceptually much closer to something like React than it is to MVC, it's really important to understand there's something along the lines of a shadow-DOM in the background.

[This page has some good pointers](https://learn-blazor.com/pages/data-binding/) on data binding in Blazor.

Comment: What?!  Rendering components dynamically is incredibly useful and very common.  How would you, for instance, handle a polymorphic list of components where every member implements its own unique visual presentation which can't be determined at compile time because they may be extermal plugin component?  Your approach falls flat on its face in this scenario.

Comment: Hi @ATL_DEV. It probably slightly depends on how broad or narrow the definition of 'dynamic' is, I've updated my answer to try and make that clearer.  I certainly agree it's a very useful facility, but I wouldn't personally say it was that common, for example we've just written a large line of business app in Blazor and not used `RenderFragment` once.  The scenario of polymorphic rendering of external plugins would definitely be an excellent use of `RenderFragment` though.  The Blazor team are looking to improve polymorphic handling by the way, see the github link in my answer.

Comment: in real world you often have to work with existing javascript based solution that require additional setup on js side - so you could create a base element on blazor side and notify js to do required steps for integration. keep in mind that doing so requires a round trip that can cause noticeable delays if you working with a lot of elements ( like on Initialization ) - so this function should be able to handle multiple elements at once

Answer (score 7):

`<DynamicComponent>` makes this all relatively trivial to do. It is one of the core additions of .NET 6, which will formally be released Nov 2021.

I'm exploring it now on RC2, and finding it quite straightforward to use, though documentation on different usage patterns is sparse.

Here are two of the best implementation references I've found;

- [Dynamically-rendered ASP.NET Core Razor components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/dynamiccomponent?view=aspnetcore-6.0) - For basic implementation and passing data in to your dynamic component.
- [Blazor .NET 6 - Dynamic Components - 4 Examples of DynamicComponent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6JIADmG2kxo&ab_channel=gavilanch3) - Includes alternative ways to wrap and integrate your component, and to wire up events.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you could do something like this too utilizing the `BuildRenderTree` but often not recommended due to ability to mess it up. ([Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/advanced-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-5.0))

```
public class CustomLabel: ComponentBase
{  
    [Parameter] public string Id { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string? Label { get; set; }

    protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Label))
        {
            builder.OpenElement(1, "label");
            builder.AddAttribute(2, "for", Id);
            builder.AddAttribute(3, "class", "custom-css-classes-here");
            builder.AddContent(4, Label);
            builder.CloseElement();
        }
    }

    // another example: maybe you would have an "IsRequired" flag 
    // that would add an "*" after the label if set to true
}
```