# Add/load components dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

Good Blazor people, I need your help.

Today when adding components to a page, you normally do something like this:

```
@page "/somepage"

<MyComponent></MyComponent>
```

What I want to do is to add the components dynamically, something like this:

```
@page "/somepage"

@dynamicComponent

@functions{
 BlazorComponent dynamicComponent = Activator.CreateInstance<Components.MyComponent>();
}
```

Any ideas how to do this, adding or loading components dynamically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blazor - How to create Components dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50117932/blazor-how-to-create-components-dynamically)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/advanced-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-3.1#manual-rendertreebuilder-logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no high level API's for this at the moment. You can use low level API's as explained here: https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/723

In your case this would translate to:

```
@page "/somepage"

@dynamicComponent()

@functions{
  RenderFragment dynamicComponent() => builder =>
    {
        builder.OpenComponent(0, typeof(SurveyPrompt));
        builder.AddAttribute(1, "Title", "Some title");
        builder.CloseComponent();
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed:
RenderFragment dynamicComponent() => builder =>
    {
        builder.OpenComponent<SurveyPrompt>(0);
        builder.CloseComponent();
    };

Comment: Hi, this doesn't work any more.
It's exactly what I want to do but it doesn't compile in a web assembly blazor app in 3.1.

Comment: @sanepete I confirm it works in a Blazor WASM .NET Standard 2.1 app

Answer (score 0):

Update as this thread has a high Google rank...

Take a look at the new DynamicComponent control in ASP.NET Core Blazor and MVC 6.0. (To be released in .NET 6.0 and currently available in preview):

https://www.daveabrock.com/2021/04/08/blazor-dynamic-component/