# add list of dynamic components in blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I just started to have a look in blazor (v0.3) and doing some test I wanted to add a list using blazor

First I created a `List<string>` to test a simple list in the same page

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var item in listItems)
    {
        <li>@item</li>
    }
</ul>


@functions {

    private List<string> listItems = new List<string>();
    private string newItem;

    private void AddItem()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(newItem))
            return;

        listItems.Add(newItem);
        newItem = "";
    }

}
```

this is working fine, is adding every element to the list when I add it. but then, i tried to add components, add a single component was easy, based on this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50117932/blazor-how-to-create-components-dynamically) but for a list I had the next problem:

- I created a `<li>` compontent just to test the functionality of components, here is the component view

> ```
> <li id="@ID">
>     @Text
> </li>   
>
>
>
>
> @functions {
>   [Parameter]
>   string Text { get; set; } 
>   [Parameter]
>   string ID { get; set; }
> }
> ```

- then in the parent view

> ```
> <input type="text" bind="TxtExample" name="inpAdd"/>
>   <button onclick="@addCompoment">add comp1</button>
> <div class="simple-list-list">
> ```

```
    @if (!componentListTest.Any())
    {
        <p>You have no items in your list</p>
    }
    else
    {
        <ul>
            @foreach (var item in componentListTest)
            {
                @item
            }
        </ul>
    }
</div>

@functions {

    private List<RenderFragment> componentListTest { get; set; }
    private int currentCount {get; set;}
    private string TxtExample { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInit()
    {
        currentCount = 0;
        componentListTest = new List<RenderFragment>();
    }


    protected void addCompoment()
    {

        componentListTest.Add(CreateDynamicComponent(currentCount));
        currentCount++;
    }


    RenderFragment CreateDynamicComponent(int counter) => builder =>
    {
        var seq = 0;
        builder.OpenComponent(seq, typeof(listExample));
        builder.AddAttribute(++seq, "Text", "text --  "+TxtExample);
        builder.AddAttribute(++seq, "id","listed-"+counter);

        builder.CloseComponent();

    };
}
```

when I load the fist element is loaded correctly:
[image]

but when I entered the second one, all of them are replaced for the last one:

[image]

Any idea whats going on?

Comment: I would advice to use the most recent version, which is 0.3 at the moment.

Comment: yup is 0.3 not 0.2

Answer (score 5):

You are making it too complicated. You don't need to dynamically instantiate components for this scenario to work.

You can just do a:

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var item in listItems)
    {
        <myComponent bind-myVar="@item"></myComponent>
    }
</ul>
```

And the components will be instantiated for you.

Also see [here](https://blazor.net/docs/components/index.html) how to make the parameters work on your component.

Comment: mi issue is not do the list, the issue is load components dynamically. I will have a look on the link btw

Comment: My point is, that in 99% of the cases you don't need to instantiate programmatically.

Comment: Haha I've been searching for an answer for a while and completely forget that THIS is the way you're mean to add dynamic content. Thank you reminding me. I guess it's going to take a while for some of us to move away from the old mindset of adding content to the DOM

Comment: It may be a good choice for his use case, since all the objects on the list are of the same type.  It's not a good choice if your list is composed of polymorphic objects. Let's say he has a collection of Fruit type. The list can contain bananas, apples and oranges, which are descendents of Fruit type. Assume they will be rendered differently.  Using parameters only loses all the benefits of encapsulation and separation of concerns, since the enclosing component will need to know how to render each fruit. Moreover, adding another type will require a change to the enclosing component as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `TxtExample` is global to the component. When Blazor detects a potential UI change, it recalculates the entire component and updates the DOM with any differences. So when you change the textbox, `TxtExample` is updated and then the Razor is recalculating, inserting the new value of `TxtExample` for all rows.

Comment: I know what you mean, but in the first example `List<string>` `@newItem` is also global to the component. but when I add an item, all the old items keep the values. any idea?

Comment: I'm a little confused how the `CreateDynamicComponent` lambda is working, such as where `builder` is coming from, or what `listExample` is, but I'm guessing that the `RenderFragment` is being recalculated every time, whereas `newItem` isn't since it's a value type. Try creating a list of strings, representing all the entries of `TxtExample` so that it can loop through that and display an entry for each.