# How to load Blazor component/view into a specific div

Tags: blazor

In JavaScript one can load a view into a specific container or div  like using   `$("#div1").load("/Home/GetPartial")`. How do I achieve the same in Blazor where I want to be able to specify which div in a page gets loaded with a view/component and also pass parameter along.

Comment: It might be worth editing the question to address the following:  Is the page your trying to load the component into another Blazor component, an MVC page, a Razor Page or a general HTML page?  is this server side or client side Blazor?  Also, are you wanting to do this dynamically in response to some other JS event, or is this just loading the component into the page once?

Comment: @tomRedox thanks for exposing the various possibilities/scenarios. I definitely will have need for both blazor component and an MVC page. Would be grateful for a case of a razor page too. Your guidance please.

Comment: @tomRedox Guess I left out some important questions. Am considering client side blazor and I don't intend to use any java script. I just want a situation where I could dynamically specify which div of the 3 div columns a Blazor component is rendered with the required data passed to it as you would do append to a div in a java script call to return a partial view.

Comment: did my response answer your question?

Comment: @tomRedox great direction you gave, looking at your explanation in the other so question you pointed at using foreach with switch. I was hoping for something like  <@theComponent/>  @code{ string theComponent = "page1";}

Answer (score 1):

### Rendering a Blazor component conditionally on a MVC or Razor Page

The `RenderComponentAsync`  method can be used to render a Blazor component onto an MVC or Razor page in a specific location.

You can then use conditional rendering in the same way as you would in normal MVC/Razor to determine where on the page the component should be rendered.

In the example below my Razor Page has a property called `CaseId` in its code behind model, but that could equally be a variable declared in the code section of on an MVC page and retrieved from the parameters of the URL.

```cs
<div class='new-column'>
  @if (Model.Status = "New")
  {
    @(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<SprintCase>(RenderMode.Server,
      new { CaseId = Model.CaseId }))
  }
</div>

<div class='in-progress-column'>
  @if (Model.Status  = "In Progress")
  {
    @(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<SprintCase>(RenderMode.Server,
      new { CaseId = Model.CaseId }))
  }
</div>

<div class='complete-column'>
  @if (Model.Status = "Complete")
  {
    @(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<SprintCase>(RenderMode.Server,
      new { CaseId = Model.CaseId }))
  }
</div>
```

That should work for getting the component rendered into the correct location on first load.

If you then want to dynamically update the MVC/Razor page, without reloading the whole page, I think you should be able to that in the same way as you would normally with a partial view in MVC, i.e. have a controller endpoint that returns a partial view that contains the code above and that should render in the same way as if the partial was just returning HTML. I haven't tried that so I'm not completely certain.

You'll also need to get Blazor running in your MVC app, there's [more on that here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56241125/1879019).

### Rendering a Blazor component conditionally in another Blazor component

This case is much simpler, you simply need a property in either your component's `@code` block, or some other property to perform the switch on.  Whenever that property changes the component should then re-render automatically, but if it doesn't you can give it a prompt by calling `StateHasChanged`

```cs
<div class='new-column'>
  @if (Model.Status = "New")
  {
    <SprintCase CaseId=Model.CaseId />
  }
</div>

<div class='in-progress-column'>
  @if (Model.Status  = "In Progress")
  {
    <SprintCase CaseId=Model.CaseId />
  }
</div>

<div class='complete-column'>
  @if (Model.Status = "Complete")
  {
    <SprintCase CaseId=Model.CaseId />
  }
</div>

@code {
  private SprintCase Model { get; set; }

}
```

Where `SprintCase` is the name of the Blazor component you want to conditionally render.

I've written a lot more about dynamic/conditional component rendering in [this answer too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56046499/1879019).

Comment: could the component name be dynamically replace base on the value of another parameter like 
    <code> @(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<@SprintCase>(RenderMode.Server,
      new { CaseId = Model.CaseId }))</code>
      new { CaseId = Model.CaseId }))